# spark sql error - org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I was able to get max partitioned date value using the Query 1 - sql statement below in spark-shell.

Query 1:

```
spark.sql("show partitions default.test_tbl1").select(regexp_extract(col("partition"),exp = "(\\/|^)trans_dt=(\\S+?)(\\/|$$)",groupIdx = 2).alias("trans_dt")).where(trans_dt < 20221031).select(max(col("trans_dt")))
```

But when Query 1 combined with other sql statement like in Query 2, it is throwing an error message.

Query 2:

```
spark.sql(s"""select * from default.test_tbl2 where trans_dt IN ((show partitions default.test_tbl1).select(regexp_extract(col(partition),exp = (\\/|^)trans_dt=(\\S+?)(\\/|$$),groupIdx = 2).alias(trans_dt)).where(trans_dt < 20221031).select(max(col(trans_dt))))""")
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
>
> mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 9)

I would like to know what is wrong in Query 2 to retrieve result for max partitioned date value.

Comment: You are trying to mix and match dialects in an invalid way. You are using the dataframe API syntax directly in a sql query. That's just not the way the language works.